# Get user IP over proxy.

Tags: php, html, get, ip

I'm not able to get the users ip in the regular way due to tcp proxying.
So I need an alternative.

I tried this:

```
$ip = file_get_contents('http://wtfismyip.com/text');
```

Output was server ip.
Is there any way I can get the users ip?

Comment: Means you can't get client IP using this `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`???

Comment: Which language and which server you are using ? You should give us more detail.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways you can do this.

Depending on the proxy you might want to see if x-forwarded-for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For is set.

Jou could have a JS on the client check the IP and send it with your request. [How to get client's IP address using javascript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript)